# Simplifying cos and sin to write in terms of x+iy?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Was solving a complex problem, and I got stuck when trying to convert my answer into terms of x+iy. I'm not sure how to reduce cos(w)+i sin(w) in terms of x+iy when w = -π/18; 11π/18; 23π/18...
I tried to figure out where it would lie on the unit circle, but I'm lost at this point. Any hints or strategies on how to solve this or how to write it in terms of x+iy?

Comment: Haven't you done so already? Take $x=\cos(w)$, $y=\sin(w)$.

Comment: Are you basically asking for an exact value for $\cos \frac{\pi}{18}$ and similar?

Comment: x,y and real numbers and cos,sin for the value you mentioned are real numbers

Comment: I didn't think of it this way... I thought I had to simplify further that's probably why I was confused Thanks to all!

Comment: It is known that an angle in a whole number $d$ of degrees can be constructed using ruler and compass iff $d$ is a multiple of $3.$ Your angles are not. I don't know if this rules out any simple closed forms for your desired cosine and sine values, but it shows it would not be simple.